# Method With Parameter In Parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, void

I want to pass a method with a parameter in a parameter like this. But it still got error and i didn't know what to do.

```
void WriteInScreen(string text){
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
void WriteInScreen10Times(string text){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
void CallWriteInScreen(Action Method) {
    Method();
}
void StartCall(){
    //Error: Argument 2: Can't not convert from void to System.Action
    CallWriteInScreen(WriteInScreen("Hello!"));
    CallWriteInScreen(WriteInScreen10Time("Hi!"));
}
```

This is just my test code, i need to solve this to continue develop my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CallWriteToScreen` only accepts a delegate that accepts no parameters and produces no result (a.k.a an `Action`). Not sure whether you want to create a family of `CallWriteToScreen` methods that accept parameterized `Action`s:

```
void CallWriteInScreen(Action Method) {
    Method();
}
void CallWriteInScreen<T1>(Action<T1> Method, T1 arg1) {
    Method(arg1);
}
void CallWriteInScreen<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> Method, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) {
    Method(arg1, arg2);
}
void StartCall(){
    CallWriteInScreen(WriteInScreen, "Hello!");
    CallWriteInScreen(WriteInScreen10Time, "Hi!");
}
```

or just want to wrap the eventual method call up:

```
void StartCall(){
    CallWriteInScreen(() => WriteInScreen("Hello!"));
    CallWriteInScreen(() => WriteInScreen10Time("Hi!"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not do this

```
CallWriteInScreen(WriteInScreen10Time("Hi!"));
```

because the method you defined: WriteInScreen10Time("Hi!")
returns void so you would be passing void to the method CallWriteInScreen which expects an Action as paramter

Comment: So do you know how to do this, please let me know!

Comment: use delegates...